# Local http-server is not connecting to the firebase user

Tags: html, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, simplehttpserver

I am using Visual Studio Code editor and node js HTTP server. I have created the a simple login page and created a user in `firebase`. but i didn't able to login using the username. I wrote code for web page in HTML and bootstrap.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-dark">
    <div id="login-card" class="card">                
        <div class="card-body">
            <h1>Wallpaper App Admin</h1>
            <form id="login-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script>
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
            if(user){
                window.location.href="admin.html";
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css file**

```
#login-card{
width:450px;
margin:150px auto;
}
```

**app.js File**

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBF2wl4WHBbLHg90M3lAk_dNKZ7SAo0iE8",
    authDomain: "wallpaper-app-b7c7b.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://wallpaper-app-b7c7b.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "wallpaper-app-b7c7b",
    storageBucket: "wallpaper-app-b7c7b.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "302819877773"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.auth.Auth.persistence.LOCAL;

$("#btn-login").click(function(){

    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    var result = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    result.catch(function(error){
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage);
    });
});
```

**admin.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the Admin Page</h1>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script>
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
            if(!user){
                window.location.href="index.html";
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the exact error message you are seeing?

Comment: I am seeing any error message...I am just not able to login to goto the admin.html page

Comment: i have searched alot i am created user in firebase and in the authorized domain section  i see local host domain but i am using is localhost:8080 i tried to ass my domain but it is showing some error.. what else i can do. please tell me.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LOCAL' of undefined
    at app.js:11    I am seeing this error in browser Console

Comment: you dont need the line `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL`, as the default value is already `local`, 
also the proper way to call it should be `firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)`

Comment: I remove the line it is worked. but if i open the project it is automatically going to the admin page. and i tried firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL); this statement also but the same problem (automatically going to admin.html page)is happening

Comment: because in your `app.js` you had `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged() }`. On every time you init the firebase auth sdk, if the user is logged-in, this function is triggered with the logged-in user automatically. Maybe you need `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION` or even `NONE`

Comment: I am re-posting the above comments as answer if it works no problem

Comment: it is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

The line `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL` is causing error, there are two problems.

1. The default value is already `LOCAL`, so it is not necessary to define it.
2. The proper way to define persistence is
   `firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)`